Consent for multiple photos at a UK sports event
Given this situation:

a photographer working for a UK sports venue where general public can attend (with tickets)
photos taken are of of various different types, wide group shots down to individuals enjoing their time at a particular event
sometimes some photos might be used in advertising artwork by said venue, but the photographer will not be aware which photos will be used

Would the venue need consent/permission from every single person that ends up on their photos? The venue intends to collect name, email and the photo id.

You've presented a pretty vague scenario. I think if a definitive answer is really important to you, then you shouldn't rely on just what you find online - you need to speak to a specialist. There are probably different legal obligations/implications that all need to be considered in parallel.


Would the venue need consent/permission from every single person that ends up on their photos?

No, in the UK there is no "right of likeness," image rights, nor concept of personal privacy when in public (i.e. you don't need permission to take someone's picture).
There's only two possible related issues with commercial use in the UK; passing off, and endorsement. And neither is likely to be relevant in this situation.
However, as Philip mentioned, where they are much more likely to get into trouble is in collecting and storing PII/privacy data.

Yes. You typically sign away all your rights as part of the very long list of T&Cs you agree to when you buy the ticket for an event.
On a very related but off-topic for photography note

The venue intends to collect name, email and the photo id.

Photo rights are going to be the least of their problems if they're doing this without a very good understanding of their GDPR (and successor) responsibilities.
